# Self hosted WCF service in Mono

Tags: c#, wcf, mono, self-hosting

I am currently working on a C# project which is a console app which has a WCF soap service hosted within it.

Below is the code I am using to open the host.

```
var baseAddress = new Uri(Configuration.soapServerSettings.soapServerUrl);
var host = new ServiceHost(typeof(SoapServer), baseAddress);
BasicHttpBinding basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();

var meta = new ServiceMetadataBehavior()
{
    HttpGetEnabled = true,
    HttpGetUrl = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative)
};

host.Description.Behaviors.Add(meta);

var debugBehaviour = new ServiceDebugBehavior()
{
    HttpHelpPageEnabled = true,
    HttpHelpPageUrl = new Uri("", UriKind.Relative),
    IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults = true
};

ServiceEndpoint endpnt = host.AddServiceEndpoint(
    typeof(ISoapInterface),
    basicHttpBinding,
    "EmailServer");

host.Description.Behaviors.Remove(typeof(ServiceDebugBehavior));
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(debugBehaviour);
host.Open();
```

This is working perfectly fine on Windows but on Linux when I get I browse to it I get the following message:

> XmlSchema error: Named item
>   http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/:anyType was
>   already contained in the schema object table. Consider setting
>   MONO_STRICT_MS_COMPLIANT to 'yes' to mimic MS implementation. Related
>   schema item SourceUri: , Line 3, Position 3.

I have no idea where to start looking into this problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide

**Update:**
As per Rob Goodwins suggestion, I've added the `MONO_STRICT_MS_COMPLIANT` as the environment variable which does seem to have worked I can access the service. However, I am getting a different problem now. I have a PHP page which does several requests every couple of seconds but then after a minute, my app crashes.

I get the following exception:

> This XmlWriter does not accept StartTag at this state Error.   at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement (System.String prefix,
>   System.String localName, System.String namespaceUri) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Xml.DefaultXmlWriter.WriteStartElement (System.String prefix,
>   System.String localName, System.String ns) [0x00000] in :0   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteStartElement (System.String
>   localName, System.String ns) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Logger.TraceCore (TraceEventType eventType, Int32
>   id, Boolean hasRelatedActivity, Guid relatedActivity, System.Object[]
>   data) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Logger.LogMessage
>   (System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.MessageLogTraceRecord log) [0x00000]
>   in :0   at System.ServiceModel.Logger.LogMessage
>   (MessageLogSourceKind sourceKind,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message& msg, Int64 maxMessageSize)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpRequestContext.InternalReply
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000]
>   in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Http.HttpRequestContext.Reply
>   (System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message msg, TimeSpan timeout) [0x00000]
>   in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext.Reply (Boolean
>   useTimeout) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationInvokerHandler.Reply
>   (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc, Boolean
>   useTimeout) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.OperationInvokerHandler.ProcessRequest
>   (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.BaseRequestProcessorHandler.ProcessRequestChain
>   (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.BaseRequestProcessorHandler.ProcessRequestChain
>   (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.HandlersChain.ProcessRequestChain
>   (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.BaseRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest
>   (System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageProcessingContext mrc)
>   [0x00000] in :0
>
> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: This XmlWriter
>   does not accept StartTag at this state Error.   at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextWriter.WriteStartElement (System.String prefix,
>   System.String localName, System.String namespaceUri) [0x00000] in
>   :0   at
>   System.Xml.DefaultXmlWriter.WriteStartElement (System.String prefix,
>   System.String localName, System.String ns) [0x00000] in :0   at System.Xml.XmlWriter.WriteStartElement (System.String
>   localName, System.String ns) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Logger.TraceCore (TraceEventType eventType, Int32
>   id, Boolean hasRelatedActivity, Guid relatedActivity, System.Object[]
>   data) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Logger.Log (TraceEventType eventType,
>   System.String message, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0   at System.ServiceModel.Logger.Error (System.String
>   message, System.Object[] args) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ListenerLoopManager.ProcessErrorWithHandlers
>   (IChannel ch, System.Exception ex,
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message& res) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ListenerLoopManager.ProcessRequest
>   (IReplyChannel reply, System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContext rc)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ListenerLoopManager.TryReceiveRequestDone
>   (IAsyncResult result) [0x00000] in :0

I also don't seem to be able to access the service via VS2010 WCF Test Client, it doesn't error it just sits there with the progress bar at 50% and doesn't get any further.

In the apache error log I get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: Should be something like
>   [[hostname:]port:]VPath:realpath   at
>   Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer.AddApplicationsFromCommandLine
>   (System.String applications) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer:AddApplicationsFromCommandLine
>   (string)   at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.RealMain (System.String[]
>   args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server:RealMain
>   (string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool)   at
>   Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0 [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:
>   System.ArgumentException: Should be something like
>   [[hostname:]port:]VPath:realpath   at
>   Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer.AddApplicationsFromCommandLine
>   (System.String applications) [0x00000] in :0   at
>   (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check)
>   Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer:AddApplicationsFromCommandLine
>   (string)   at Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.RealMain (System.String[]
>   args, Boolean root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet)
>   [0x00000] in :0   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server:RealMain
>   (string[],bool,Mono.WebServer.IApplicationHost,bool)   at
>   Mono.WebServer.Apache.Server.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in
>   :0

**Update 2:**
I seem to have it kind of working now except I can only access the service locally. I.e. the web service can be accessed locally and the functions do what they should, but I can't access it from another PC. I.e. I am trying to access the WCF service on the Mono server using the WCF test client from my dev PC from dev PC and I am then getting the following output:

> Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from `http://192.168.1.74:6525/` If this
>   is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have
>   access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the
>   specified address.  For help enabling metadata publishing, please
>   refer to the MSDN documentation at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=65455.WS-Metadata Exchange
>   Error    URI: `http://192.168.1.74:6525/`    Metadata contains a
>   reference that cannot be resolved: `'http://192.168.1.74:6525/`'.
>   Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by
>   service `http://192.168.1.74:6525/`.  The client and service bindings
>   may be mismatched.    The remote server returned an error: (415)
>   Expected content-type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8' but got
>   'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8'.HTTP GET Error    URI:
>   `http://192.168.1.74:6525/`    The document was understood, but it could
>   not be processed.  - The WSDL document contains links that could not
>   be resolved.  - There was an error downloading
>   '`http://localhost:6525/?xsd=xsd0`'.  - Unable to connect to the remote
>   server  - No connection could be made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 127.0.0.1:6525.

**Update 3:**
Upon further testing it looks as if when many calls are made into the service in one go. Constantly hiting refresh on the browser page making use of the service seems to crash it.

It looks as if there is something wrong with the `System.ServiceModel.Logger.TraceCore` within Mono. Is there a way to disable this part of mono so I don't get affected by this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to use advice from your error message, setting MONO_STRICT_MS_COMPLIANT to yes ? check this blog post http://erictummers.wordpress.com/2012/01/24/wsdl-in-mono/

Comment: I haven't been able to find where this is set

Comment: I believe it is a environment variable

Comment: @RobGoodwin You're right its more a less working now except after a couple of requests it crashes. I've updated the question with more details

Comment: Mono is open source, just grab the dammned TraceCore.cs file and try to fix the bug

Comment: Which version of mono are you using? In Ubuntu I've built it myself from the sources (it's easy) because the version that comes with Ubuntu can be a bit aged.

Comment: I'm not sure now, OpenSuse released a new version which I have now upgraded to and so far, this seems to have resolved the issue

Comment: WCF is a bit flaky in Mono - personally, I would use another solution rather than trying to get it working. http://www.mono-project.com/WCF_Development

Answer (score 1):

It seems there may me some permission related problems from the hosting server, please check once for the permissions given to the particular port. Hope this may be useful.

Comment: Other clients are able to connect to it though, such as the WCF test client within vs2010